# how does python ensure it is mutable after dynamic resizing under the hood

Tags: python

I understand that the list in Python is under the hood a dynamic array of pointers  but I am confused how mutability of list is ensured when passing it to the function.

```
samplelist = [4,"string",5,6]

def listAppend(list):
    for i in range(10000):
        list.append("6")

listAppend(samplelist)
```

and if I pass the list to a function (passing reference by value) and append elements to the list in a loop until it requires dynamic resizing under the hood, how does Python ensure that the samplelist object(id) remains the same as list object(id) even after dynamic resizing inside the function after repeated append calls? Is that because what happens under the hood is you have a head pointer to a array of pointers and that head pointer changes to a different location after resizing?

Comment: "I pass the list to a function (which is by value)" - no, you are passing a reference to the list.

Comment: You are passing reference by value.

Comment: Yes, to be exact. `list2 = samplelist` is the same thing. So passing it to a function isn't really relevant. In any case, resizing a list doesn't create a new list object.

Comment: Anyway, yes, the list object maintains a pointer to the memory it uses for storage, which can be updated if necessary. Here's the cpython source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bf4ac2d2fd520c61306b2676db488adab9b5d8c5/Objects/listobject.c#L35